# how to return number of deref objects?

Tags: database, oracle, count

How can I display in the output also the number of distributors for that model?

```
select m.model_name, m.model_year, 
deref(value(c)).code as component_code, 
deref(value(c)).component_type as component_type, 
deref(value(c)).component_description as component_description,
deref(value(d)).vat as distributor_vat,
deref(value(d)).address.province as distributor_province,
deref(value(a)).colour as car_colour
from model m 
cross join table (m.component) c
cross join table (m.distributor) d
cross join table (m.car) a
where m.model_name = 'Medina';
```

I've tried to put a COUNT

```
select m.model_name, m.model_year, 
deref(value(c)).code as component_code, 
deref(value(c)).component_type as component_type, 
deref(value(c)).component_description as component_description,
deref(value(d)).vat as distributor_vat,
deref(value(d)).address.province as distributor_province,
deref(value(a)).colour as car_colour,
COUNT(deref(value(d)).vat) AS '#_of_Distributor'
from model m 
cross join table (m.component) c
cross join table (m.distributor) d
cross join table (m.car) a
where m.model_name = 'Medina';
```

but of course I get an error.